# Accessing font-family on visited website

Tags: html, css, font-face

I just visited a website and I liked the font used in it.how can I access the source of the file on that website which uses @font-face(I think)?

Comment: In Chrome and IE: hit F12, In FF, use Firebug. That will show you all used resources, html, images, css and javascript.

Comment: I don't want just the name of the font.in the css file @font-face { font-family:"something"; src:url(something.ttf); } I want to download "something.ttf" directly from the website

Answer (score 0):

The thing to do is to view the page source.

When you view the source of the page you will be able to see the stylesheet, look in that for the code.

If you want to be lazy or want a quicker way in IE, Chrome and Firefox you can press F12 to get the developer console which will show you the code in a bit of a more understandable and clearer view.

What is the website? Maybe we can help you?

Comment: I don't want just the name of the font.in the css file 
@font-face
{
font-family:"something";
src:url(something.ttf);
}
I want to download "something.ttf" directly from the website.

Comment: @beautifulmind you need the link first and then you can get the file?

Comment: @beautifulmind if that is the case, what is the website and lets take a look